# Load ObservableCollection from Xml save file to Datagrid (C#, Wpf)

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, datagrid, observablecollection

Okay so I hope it's okay if I don't post my code since it contains private parts.

I will describe it as good as I can. So I did an `observablecollection` without `onpropetychange` and a `databind` to the *grid*. Everything works well if I'm adding something to the collection, the datagrid updates. But if I get the *observablecollection* from the xml save file, it doesn't update.

So far I checked if the *observablecollection* loads everything (it does) and tried to update the datagrid manual (nothing). I'm glad if someone could give me advice without seeing the code. :)

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that you should set the DataGrid's ItemsSource property again after loading the ObservableCollection.

Use this:

```
datagrid.ItemsSource = null;
datagrid.ItemsSource = yourObservableCollection;
```

Comment: Still not working, i guess what Fruchtzwerg said is the problem, still thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing the whole collection, the UI can not recognize the change since you are not using the `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You have two options:

1. Implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and raise the event after setting a new collection as source.
2. Clear the old collection, and fill in the new items to the old collection.